# How to serialize and deserialize Listview Items in JavaFX?

Tags: listview, javafx

I am working on a GUI project that I have to use Serialization and Deserialization. Right now I am working on the contact List which has several textboxes i.e First name, Last Name, PhoneNumber etc. and a Listview. Whenever I click the "Add to contact" Button the textBoxes content gets serialized and the First Name and Last Name is added to the Listview. My problem is how can I serialize the Listview Items, they are all string. Is there a way I can add those data to `ArrayList`? and also How can I deserialize the data when my application loads? I have a deserialization method but do not know how to implement it in `initialize()` method. Thank you!

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> listView_Contact;

private final ObservableList<String> myContactList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize an `ArrayList` containing the strings:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ... ;
oos.writeObject(new ArrayList<String>(myContactList));
```

and just set all the values in the observable list when you deserialize them:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = ... ;
myContactList.setAll((List<String>)ois.readObject());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked! however I am having trouble serializing the data from the textbox. I have a serialization method which serializes all the textbox data but when I enter a new data it overwrites the previous data. Is there anyway I can append those data?